# Velocity hangs with no errors when testing meteor app

Tags: meteor, meteor-velocity

I'm pretty new to meteor so I'm just writing a simple app but really want to make it as TDD as possible (worth mentioning I'm also new to Mocha). So I've added the `mike:mocha` and `velocity:core` packages and written a super simple initial test just to see if I can get things to work, which I've added at *tests/mocha/client/tests.js*:

```
if (typeof MochaWeb != 'undefined') {
 MochaWeb.testOnly(function () {

   describe('Friends are added successfully', function () {

     it('Should add a new person to the Friend collection', function(done) {
       var friendId = Friends.insert(
           { firstName: 'New',
           lastName: 'Friend'});

       var friend = Friends.findOne({'firstName':'New'});
       console.log(friend);
       chai.assert.equal(friend.length === 1);
       done();
     });
   });
  })
;}
```

My problem is that when I run either the `meteor` command or `meteor --test`, I get nothing in the terminal apart from the expected:

```
=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.I20150115-22:31:03.216(0)? [velocity] chokadir watching /correctDirectory/tests
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
```

But then Velocity just hangs (a blue circle with a wider blue ring around it - no greens or red), pulsating and not providing any feedback whatsoever. None on the developer console or the terminal either! I tried checking localhost:5000 but this comes back as 'not available'.

Not sure how to start with figuring this one out!

Thanks in advance to anyone who can help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to get your example to work on my local, so I would recommend checking versions of your software and get that in line first.

Here are a few things you can check, but I'll show what's on my machine for comparison:

- **Check your version of node**

  `node -v`

  *v0.10.35*
- **If necessary, upgrade node**. On my mac, I do the following:

  `brew update && brew upgrade node`

  *If you don't have a mac, you might want to google for upgrade instructions for your machine's platform.*
- **Check your package versions**

  `meteor list`

  *meteor-platform  1.2.1*

  *mike:mocha       0.5.1*

  *velocity:core    0.4.5*
- **Check your meteor version**

  `meteor --version`

  *Meteor 1.0.2.1*
- **If necessary, upgrade meteor and related packages**

  `meteor update`

If none of that helps, please post additional information. Additionally, you can also create an issue on Github for **[Velocity](https://github.com/meteor-velocity/velocity/issues)**.

Comment: Hooray! Thanks, I had to specifically force the mike:mocha package to update to the version you mentioned above using `meteor add mike:mocha@0.5.1`, it was stuck at 0.4.4

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it.